# COUNT em várias tabelas

Tags: mysql, count

Tenho duas tabelas no meu sistema, e preciso fazer uma contagem de duas colunas nas tabelas. Atualmente faço através de uma VIEW da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE VIEW totais AS
(SELECT (SELECT COUNT(publications.id) FROM publications) AS total1,
(SELECT COUNT(deejays.id) FROM deejays) AS total2)
```

Preciso fazer através de um SELECT mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: E por que não pode usar a `VIEW`? Não sei se notou, ela é um `SELECT`.

Comment: @bigown `SELECT COUNT(publications.id) as total1, COUNT(deejays.id) as total2 from publications, deejays` não daria certo?

Comment: @R.Santos não vejo porque não daria ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(publications.id) FROM publications) AS total1,
  (SELECT COUNT(deejays.id) FROM deejays) AS total2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Um modo que poderia ser feito também é o seguinte:

```
SELECT COUNT(publications.id) as total1, 
COUNT(deejays.id) as total2 
from publications, deejays
```

Comment: o resultados ficam iguais nas duas variáveis. tipo o count fica igual em ambos.

Comment: @FlávioKowalske, Como assim?

Comment: em uma tabela tenho 10 registros e na outra 4. quando rodo a consulta retorna 40 em ambas as variáveis.